# Do you need License for OS (Windows) inside Docker

Tags: windows, docker, operating-system, licensing

I am looking at creating a Docker (set) for applications that run on Windows. So, I need the Docker to have Windows OS. What license do I need for it? Or if I run the Docker on a Windows VM, does it make use of the same license from the Host?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The container images will use the underlying OS license. Microsoft calls it [supplmental license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/images-eula).

> You are licensed to use this Supplement in conjunction with the
>   underlying host operating system software (“Host Software”) solely to
>   assist running the containers feature in the Host Software. The Host
>   Software license terms apply to your use of the Supplement. You may
>   not use it if you do not have a license for the Host Software. You may
>   use this Supplement with each validly licensed copy of the Host
>   Software.

Comment: Thanks. And so, does this mean I can run multiple containers on one host?

Comment: Does it mean that, a user of a publicly published image should get a license for the host OS first before running the image even if the host OS is invisible to him (e.g. hidden by host providers)?

Comment: Host providers usually charge you for the licensed machine. So If your host windows is licensed you should be fine. aws documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/licensing/

Comment: The docker hub pages for ms containers have a copy of the license agreements as stated above.
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images#license

Comment: Worth noting that for non-HyperV containers, a Windows 10/11 container is for non-production use only. It's in the "Additional Terms" section.